# Speech Recognition in android that can work offline

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android app.
I need to use Speech Recognition in my app.

I have tried doing it by **Recognizer Intent** of android but it only works through Internet and I need it to work without INTERNET.

**Is there any library for Speech Recognition that can work offline?** or **Is there any possible way to make Recognizer Intent work OFFLINE?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *all* versions of Android, across devices, across languages, with full vocabulary?

I guess you could try something like [PocketSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/), but bear in mind that older devices don't have a lot of horsepower, and that's the problem. Connectivity allows a huge corpus.

You could also use an app like [Voice Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.KnJSoftware.VoiceCommander&hl=en) or [Utter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brandall.nutter&hl=en) and hook in to your app: this is likely much, much easier than doing it yourself.

JellyBean devices have this functionality built-in, [it just needs to be enabled](http://androidwidgetcenter.com/android-tips/how-to-use-offline-speech-recognition-in-jelly-bean/).

Comment: How do I manually import PocketSphinx in AIDE??

Answer (score 0):

Another options to use:

1) use IVONA TTS engine (it also lets you recognize speech offline)
it reqires 150 MB of space (with english language installed alone)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ivona.tts&hl=en

2) you can use a workaround for using google offline libraries on android 4.1+ (in case you also can not download them from the system settings), but is not easy and requires root

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=47997173

btw I tested IVONA TTS with Utter and it could recognize my speech offline, so it should work